# Difficulty using Kubernetes Persistent Volume Claims with Amazon EBS

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

I'm attempting to follow the instructions at https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/cluster/addons/registry to add a private docker registry to Kubernetes, but the pod created by the rc isn't able to mount the persistent volume claim.

First I'm creating a volume on EBS like so:

```
aws ec2 create-volume --region us-west-1 --availability-zone us-west-1a --size 32 --volume-type gp2
```

(`us-west-1a` is also the availability zone that all of my kube minions are running in.)

Then I create a persistent volume like so:

```
kind: PersistentVolume
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: kube-system-kube-registry-pv
  labels:
    kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 30Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  awsElasticBlockStore:
    volumeID: vol-XXXXXXXX
    fsType: ext4
```

And a claim on the persistent volume like so:

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: kube-registry-pvc
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 30Gi
```

The replication controller is specified like so:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
  name: kube-registry-v0
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: kube-registry
    version: v0
    kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    k8s-app: kube-registry
    version: v0
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: kube-registry
        version: v0
        kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: registry
        image: registry:2
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 100Mi
        env:
        - name: REGISTRY_HTTP_ADDR
          value: :5000
        - name: REGISTRY_STORAGE_FILESYSTEM_ROOTDIRECTORY
          value: /var/lib/registry
        volumeMounts:
        - name: image-store
          mountPath: /var/lib/registry
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5000
          name: registry
          protocol: TCP
      volumes:
      - name: image-store
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: kube-registry-pvc
```

When I create the rc, It successfully starts a pod, but the pod is unable to mount the volume:

```
$ kubectl describe po kube-registry --namespace=kube-system
...
Events:
  FirstSeen     LastSeen        Count   From                                                    SubobjectPath   Reason          Message
  ─────────     ────────        ─────   ────                                                    ─────────────   ──────          ───────
  1m            1m              1       {scheduler }                                                            Scheduled       Successfully assigned kube-registry-v0-3jobf to XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.us-west-1.compute.internal
  22s           22s             1       {kubelet XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.us-west-1.compute.internal}                    FailedMount     Unable to mount volumes for pod "kube-registry-v0-3jobf_kube-system": Timeout waiting for volume state
  22s           22s             1       {kubelet XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.us-west-1.compute.internal}                    FailedSync      Error syncing pod, skipping: Timeout waiting for volume state
```

---

I'm able to successfully mount EBS volumes if I don't use persistent volumes and persistent volume claims.  The following works without error, for example:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test-ebs
spec:
  containers:
  - image: gcr.io/google_containers/test-webserver
    name: test-container
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /test-ebs
      name: test-volume
  volumes:
  - name: test-volume
    awsElasticBlockStore:
      volumeID: vol-XXXXXXXX
      fsType: ext4
```

---

My two questions are:

- Does anyone know what might be going wrong and how to fix it?
- In general, where can I look for more details on errors like these?  I haven't been able to find more detailed log messages anywhere, and "Unable to mount volumes...Timeout waiting for volume state" isn't terribly helpful.

Comment: Did you check the Kubernetes logs on the node where the pod was started? Your answer should be there.

Comment: I went through the same exercise and noticed that I can skip the pv and use dynamic pv provisioning instead by defining a storageclass with aws-ebs as the provisioner.  And I managed to complete the registry setup doing so.  As for trouble-shooting, use "describe".  I did encounter a pvc config bug in first try becasue aws sc1 storage requires a minimum of 500Gi and I spec'd something smaller.

Answer (score 2):

I think I was likely running into https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/15073 .  (If I create a new EBS volume, I first get a different failure, and then after the pod has been killed if I try to re-create the rc I get the failure I mentioned in my question.)

Also, for anyone else wondering where to look for logs, `/var/log/syslog` and `/var/log/containers/XXX` on the kubelet was where I ended up having to look.